# Solve the functional equation $f(x+1)-f(x)=x*\sin(x) $

Tags: functional-equations

Solve $f(x+1)-f(x)=x*\sin(x)    $

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @ArsenBerk calculus of finite differences

Answer (score 4):

Take *any* function $f(x)$ defined on $[0,1)$ and then continue to all $x$ using the equation.

Comment: Bonus: If $f$ is continuous on $[0,1)$ and $\lim_{x\to1^-}f(x)=f(0)$, then the continuoation will be continuous on all of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen but $ f(x)=1/4 csc^2(1/2) (sin(x)-x (sin(1-x)+sin(x)))$ . I don't know how to come to this decision

Comment: @colt_browning but f(x)=1/4csc2(1/2)(sin(x)−x(sin(1−x)+sin(x))) . I don't know how to come to this decision

Comment: @MorrisonFJ Why do you think it's true? Because it's the answer given in the textbook? Well, if this is known to be the correct answer, then the question is apparently missing something. Perhaps the condition that the function must be analytical? This would make the problem a lot harder.